# php, mcrypt_generic to to openssl_encrypt conversion by MCRYPT_MODE_ECB

Tags: php

Since Mcrypt is deprecated, I want to use OpenSSL instead in my code

```
        $key = md5($tenant, true);
        $iv_length = mcrypt_get_iv_size(self::$algorithm, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);//MCRYPT_RAND
        //$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(self::$algorithm, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(self::$algorithm, '', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '');
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
        $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $data);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        $result = hash('crc32', base64_encode($encrypted));
        return $result;
```

I don't know how to convert mcrypt_generic to openssl_encrypt , thanks!

Comment: Your code is missing the algorithm (DES? AES?) so it's difficult to help you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code for ECB encryption and decryption.

```
$encryptedValue = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($value,'AES-256-ECB',$key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA));
  
$decryptedValue = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encryptedValue),'AES-256-ECB',$key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
```